# JavaEE/Spring: Just call method on initialized bean using xml?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have multiple config files in my web.xml:

```
<!-- Spring MVC ========================================================================== -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MoJV_SpringMVCDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /mo/MoJV/config/MoJVConfig.xml
            /mo/App/config/AppConfig.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**In MoJVConfig.xml i have**

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="mo.MoJV.src.I18N">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8" />
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3" />

    <property name="files" value="/mo/MoJV/i18n/" />
</bean>
```

**In AppConfig.xml I would like to only call setWorkingDirectory on the same messagesource. I have tried with**

```
<bean id='messageSource'>
    <property name="files" value="/mo/App/i18n/" />
</bean>
```

but that didnt work. I have tried a bunch of other things as well which hasnt worked.

I dont want a new bean, I want the first declaration to actually run, initialize the bean and then my second declaration to call a method on that bean.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may want this

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.acme.MyClass" init-method="yourInitMethod">
    <property ...>
</bean>
```

Init-method will be called after injecting all properties and after constructor.